# Replace current css within a css file in php?

Tags: php

I have a `custom.css` with these rules:

```
div#widget {background:red !important;}
div#widget2 {background:#f0f0f0;}
div#widget2:hover {background: rgb(10,20,30);}
```

These rules could be anywhere in the `custom.css` file:

Example:

```
div#widget {background:red !important;}
.mainwrapper {background:blue;}
div#widget2 {background:#f0f0f0;}     
p {font-size:12px;}
div#widget2:hover {background: rgb(10,20,30);}
```

Now my thought is to add another css-file to overrule existing custom.css rules like this:

```
div#widget {background:yellow !important;}
div#widget2 {background:#000000 !important;}
div#widget2:hover {background: #ffffff !important;}
```

**Instead of adding a new custom css file with !important-rules** I'm thinking... Is there a way to replace current custom.css rules with the new background-colors? Is this possible to achieve (in a secure way) in php?

(Now I'm creating a new css like this)

```
$fp = fopen( "newcustom.css", 'w');
fwrite($fp, $important_css);
fclose($fp);
```

**UPDATE**
Clarification. I have a system where users can creates widgets. Widget code is created so the user could easily copy and paste it into his/her website. A reference to custom css is created for the user.

Now I'm updating the system... If I have to add new css file then the user would have to have to copy and paste a new widgetcode for the new css to work. If I could replace current custom.css then it would work "right away".

Comment: When you wants to to over-write CSS Rules at some particular situation? or just don't wanna use the previous CSS?

Comment: @hmd- what do you mean?

Comment: What is the context of this? Why do you need to override CSS?

Comment: Look, you just don't want to use the previous written Rules? if yes, `comment` that part. And if you want to do this in some particular situation, add some Class name for the situation and write a new rule for that particular Class

Comment: Updated... Clarification of the context.

Answer (score 3):

Overriding matters the ordering of your stylesheets included. So include your new css file later after the custom.css:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="custom.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="new_file.css" />
```

So, now the last rule override the first one:

```
div#widget {background:red;}
div#widget {background:blue;} /* this will work */
```

Whatsoever, the css rules defined later for the same would work.

If you don't want to change your ordering for css rules, you may define some class name per specific page and then work with that:

```
div#widget.page3_widget {background:blue;} /* this will work */
div#widget {background:red;}
```

Furthermore, you may see my [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27203293/does-the-css-direct-decendant-not-have-any-value-in-selectivity/27203341#27203341) to know how css specificity work. Knowing [css specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) rules, you may play well with your css.

Comment: Yes, I'm doing exactly that at the moment. But I'm asking if there would be away of replace current custom.css instead.

Comment: I would even go as far as to remove the unnecessary rules from the first file and include the one you need in either page

Comment: @ferdynator - what do you mean?

Comment: Have 3 files. first for all css but your widget rules. one for widget default styles and one for the new widget styles. Include the main css file plus the widget style you want

Comment: @ferdynator - as I said I'm doing exactly that - but that's not my question. The best solution in my case would be if I could replace current custom.css, and not another css.

Comment: I've updated my question. Maybe it makes things clearer -why I want to do this...

Comment: I think you wanted to remove the previous css being loaded? Then remove it before you insert new stylesheet.

Comment: " Is there a way to replace current custom.css rules " ? :-)

Comment: No. You need to replace the whole file.

Comment: Yes I understand I would have replace the file, but is there way to replace the new custom css rules within the new file created?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily add new css to your html by using jQuery.

Like `(#div_id').css('{ }');`

Comment: jQuery is not an option in my case. The css must be  created serverside.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal because always jQuery ;)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply add a Class Name for the particular HTML ELEMENT? And by doing this. Write/overwrite the current CSS RULES like:

```
div.newWidget {background:red !important;}
```